# Book where a young boy's father worked in a museum and he had to go through history

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

A young boy's father worked in a museum. He had to go through history and ends in Egypt. The boy had to collect something and there were playing cards in the back of the book.

It's a series that has 5 books.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: So is it the boy that travels through history or his father? How does he manage this feat?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This could use some more details; please review the suggestions linked above and [edit] in anything else you can think of.  Do you remember the cover of any of the books?  How long were they?  When did you read them?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/series/82657-axel-rhodes-adventures?

Comment: If the main character was a girl not a boy it would be the [Theodosia Throckmorton Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/44959-theodosia-throckmorton). The first book [Theodosia and the Serpents of Chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodosia_and_the_Serpents_of_Chaos) matches your description pretty well, and the series does have five books.